# Changing colour of a solid coloured icon when pressed

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-resources, android-drawable, android-icons

I have several small icons of a solid colour (and a photoshop made shape) on the actionbar, that needs to have a different colour when pressed.

Instead of making the state_selected as another icon (made in photoshop in a different colour), can I just fill the same drawable with another color by specifying in XML? Does this require me to define a compound drawable in some way (bitmap + colour)? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are working for API 21 (Android 5.0) you could try using `android:tint` and `android:tintMode` attributes in XML. Your `android:tint` should point to a state list defined in XML, which in your case should be something like:

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/desired_tint" />
 <item android:state_pressed="false" android:color="@color/transparent" />
 </selector>
```

For older devices, the only thing that comes to my mind is retrieving your drawable at runtime and calling

```
    drawable.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.desired_tint), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
```

as long as the view is pressed. This is probably not the best idea though.